# Bridging Header for Flurry.h not working with Pod

Tags: swift, cocoapods, flurry, bridging-header, flurry-analytics

I have an existing bridging header that currently contains several obj-c pods. I am having issue importing the Flurry framework with Xcode saying

```
'Flurry.h' file not found
```

even though it has been correctly inserted using pods.

My bridging header currently looks like

```
#import <EstimoteSDK/EstimoteSDK.h>
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import "Flurry.h" // <----- The Warning is here
```

I have tried several alternatives `#import "FlurrySDK/Flurry.h"` and `#import <Flurry.h>`

My Pod is imported with

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'FlurrySDK', '~>6.6' #Analytics
```

and is located here

[image]

Comment: Click on Podfile, and select "View in Finder". Is it in the correct directory? (Your project.)

Comment: @dannybess yeah its in the correct directory. I have other Pod imported files that are working perfectly fine.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest that makes sense, is to reinstall the library you are trying to download with Pod. Is there maybe a manual installation? - drag and drop Source files into your project.

Comment: @dannybess that seemed to do the trick. Uninstall then reinstall plus I also updated my cocopods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem wasn't Flurry Podspec. I was running an older cocoapods so updated it using

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 20):

I was having this problem with XCode 7, Flurry 7.1 and with my cocoapods setup with 'use_frameworks!'

I originally changed the bridging header import to take the umbrella header which is

```
#import <Flurry_iOS_SDK/Flurry-iOS-SDK-umbrella.h>
```

but as Allreadyhome pointed out just using the following in my swift files works the same

```
import Flurry_iOS_SDK
```

Comment: Bridging header is no longer needed. Works without it with pod `Flurry_iOS_SDK`

Comment: Worth pointing out that you import the module: `import Flurry_iOS_SDK` where you use Flurry, *not* in your bridging header.

Comment: Thanks, I try to figure it out in 30 minutes. After that I saw your post and my problem is fixed