# What is a correct bridging header for Flurry?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, flurry

I’m trying to integrate Flurry using CocoaPods in my Swift project. "pod install" downloads Flurry in the project files, but I can’t set a correct path in the bridge-file for FlurrySDK (everything is fine with all other obj-c dependencies).

[image]

Where/how can I find a correct import path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bridging Header for Flurry.h not working with Pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705925/bridging-header-for-flurry-h-not-working-with-pod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using latest `CocoaPod` to install external dependencies to Xcode Project, you don't really need the bridging header to expose `Objective-C` methods to `Swift`. See below screenshots once to understand it clearly.

Creating and Installing Pods.

[image]

Importing `Flurry SDK` in a `Swift` class.

[image]

Hope this helped. Thanks.